# Migrate TFVC to Git - Should History be migrated?

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc

I'm looking to migrate from TFVC to TFS Git.

I noticed that microsoft recommends:

- "*Due to the differences in how TFVC and Git store version control history, we recommend that you don't migrate your history.*"

...without elaborating on *why* it's not recommended.

- **What are the reasons for not migrating history when moving from TFVC to Git?**

For Info: Our codebase is ~9 years old consisting of 2 major projects with ~82k files & ~400k lines of code, and ~90k files and ~500k lines of code

Comment: How does TFVC store history?

Comment: As a series of changesets.  Equivalent to Git Commits

Comment: That's not equivalent. Git commits are snapshots of all files in the repo, not a changeset.

Comment: @evolutionbox for me that's not the technical way to store the files that is a problem. But more what and how you store it. Before the use of git-lfs, that would be silly to convert a TFVC project to git because you will end up with a too big repository containing too many huge file. Now, the remaining main problem is the way you store all your projects in a TFVC collection where they are all at the same place and possibly intricated. If your projects are well separated, migration will be still very slow but possible. Otherwise, it will be a pain and perhaps not worth it => MS recommendation..

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found this which provides some information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/devops/develop/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git

> Before attempting a migration with Git-TFS, be aware that there are fundamental differences between the way TFVC and Git store history:

> - Git stores history as a snapshot of the repository in time, while TFVC records the discrete operations that occurred on a file. Change types in TFVC like rename, undelete and rollback cannot be expressed in Git. Instead of seeing that file A was renamed to file B, it will only track that file A was deleted and file B was added in the same commit.
> - Git does not have a direct analog of a TFVC label. Labels can contain any number of files at any specific version and can reflect files at different versions. Although conceptually similar, Git tags point to a snapshot of the whole repository at a point in time. If the project relies on TFVC labels to know what was delivered, Git tags may not provide this information.
> - Merges in TFVC occur at the file level, not at the entire repository. Only a subset of changed files may be merged from one branch to another. Remaining changed files may then be merged in a subsequent changeset. In Git, a merge affects the entire repository, and both sets of individual changes cannot be seen as a merge.

> Because of these differences, it is recommended that users do a tip migration and keep their TFVC repository online, but read-only, in order to view history.